# Unity WebApi container is created every time

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

i am creating a simple web service using web api MVC 4, i am using Unity web api as my IOC, how ever in the documentation it said to add it to the application_start

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        Bootstrapper.Initialise();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

which means that for every request it is created

```
public static void Initialise()
    {
        _container = BuildUnityContainer();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(_container);
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        // register all your components with the container here

        LoggingUtilities.LoadConfigFile("ThirdParty.log4net");
        ILog log = LoggingUtilities.DefaultLogger;
        _container.RegisterInstance<ILog>(log);

        log.InfoFormat("In BuildUnityContainer");
        OpClientWrapper wrapper = new OpClientWrapper(log);

        _container.RegisterInstance<OpClientWrapper>(wrapper, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        return _container;
    }
```

i want that my Opclient wrapper will be created only once for all requests , is it possible?

Comment: Application_Start is only called once. On first request to the webservice

Comment: that i was counting on, but every request i see the call to Bootstrapper.Initialise();

Comment: Click on that method and find all references for it.:) you may find more than one reference.

Comment: strange - published it as debug as now it is ok

Answer (score 1):

`Application_Start` only fires once (see notes below) when the application starts - not per request.

Bear in mind that the following may cause the application to restart...

- Thread pool restarts
- Dropping new dlls into the bin folder
- IIS Resets

So perhaps an application start was caused "while you were watching" that made it look like it was being called more often.